# Pluralization Bugs in Docs

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, user-interface, plurals

There're a few pluralization bugs around in Documentation.

---

1. Chat Oneboxes
   "1 contributors"

[image: Image 1]

---

2. Tag Infobox

[image: Image 5]
*(Image by @JonasCz)*

Comment: Solution: request more topics, then add more topics, then write more examples.

Comment: After all, who wants to be [bludgeoned to death with a giant S](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/315822)?

Comment: It looks quite bad with all the pluralization bugs, also reported this in docs-beta before

Comment: In the chat one-box there's also "1 contributors".

Comment: how old are those screenshots? the only case I could repro was 4.

Comment: @m0sa Thanks, I forgot to test them out, they're actually from docs-beta. Updated post to reflect those unfixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Needs to be fixed in [chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chat)

2. Will be fixed in the next build (build rev `2016.8.18.3904` on sites).

Comment: 1 should be going out in the next few minutes